# How to make a thumbnail from a JPG or PNG and load it into a Timage control?

Tags: png, jpeg, thumbnails, delphi-10.2-tokyo, timage

How can I make a thumbnail from a JPG or PNG and load that thumbnail into a `TImage` control?

I've tried stuff like this, but the `TImage` does not look like is loading something.

`Image2` is a `TImage` control.

```
function resize2(source: string): TBitmap;
var
  BMPFile, ScreenBMP: TBitmap;
begin
  BMPFile := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    BMPFile.LoadFromFile(source);
    ScreenBMP := TBitmap.Create;
    ScreenBMP.PixelFormat := BMPFile.PixelFormat;
    ScreenBMP.Width := 10;
    ScreenBMP.Height := 10;
    ScreenBMP.Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect(0,0, ScreenBMP.Width, ScreenBMP.Height), BMPFile);
    Result := ScreenBMP;
  finally
    BMPFile.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TAlpha.dbeditTextBoxChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  pic1: string;
  mimapa: TBitmap;
begin
  try
    pic1 := dm.TableNotes.FieldByName('PathPic').AsVariant;
    mimapa := resize2(pic1);

    //all of these are not working
    Image2.Assign(mimapa);
    image2.Picture.Bitmap := mimapa;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VCL's [`TBitmap`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap) supports only BMP images. If you try to load any other kind of image into it, you will get an exception raised.

To load a JPG, you need to use [`TJPEGImage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.TJPEGImage) instead. To load a PNG, use [`TPNGImage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Imaging.pngimage.TPngImage) instead.

You can use a [`TPicture`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TPicture) to help you with that task, eg:

```
uses
 ..., Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Imaging.jpeg, Vcl.Imaging.pngimage;

function resize2(source: string): TBitmap;
var
  Pic: TPicture;
begin
  Pic := TPicture.Create;
  try
    Pic.LoadFromFile(source);
    Result := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      if Pic.Graphic is TBitmap then
        Result.PixelFormat := TBitmap(Pic.Graphic).PixelFormat
      else
        Result.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
      Result.Width := 10;
      Result.Height := 10;
      Result.Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect(0, 0, Result.Width, Result.Height), Pic.Graphic);
    except
      Result.Free;
      raise;
    end;
  finally
    Pic.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TAlpha.dbeditTextBoxChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  pic1: string;
  mimapa: TBitmap;
begin
  try
    pic1 := dm.TableNotes.FieldByName('PathPic').AsString;
    mimapa := resize2(pic1);
    try
      image2.Picture.Assign(mimapa);
    finally
      mimapa.Free;
    end;
    ...
  except
   ...
  end;
end;
```